# Mocking shelljs with Jest - [TypeError: shell.exec is not a function]

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

As mentioned in my previous question about mocking, I am new to Jest and testing and I seem to be getting some curveballs.

This time around I am having trouble mocking `shelljs` in my CLI application.

Automocking `jest.mock('shelljs');` didn't work and errored as:[TypeError: shell.exec is not a function]

So I went ahead and tried to use `mockImplementation()`

```
jest.mock('shelljs', () => {
  return jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
    return {
      exec: () => {}
    };
  });
});
```

To my surprise I am still getting the same error message

Any pointers would be much apprecieted.

**UPDATE 08/04/2020**:

As per Teneff's reply below, the mocking works fine with:

```
jest.mock('shelljs', () => {
  return {
    exec: jest.fn()
  };
});
```

Now I'm getting timeouts as my call of shell.exec() is async and have a callback that resolves my promise.

My goal is to mock shell.exec() to just resolve the promise, but it goes into waiting around and Jest times out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're using `shell` as an object with `.exec` property your jest.mock factory function should return an object with exec property

```
jest.mock('shelljs', () => {
  return { exec: jest.fn() }
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is being completely ignored and `shell` just goes ahead and tries to run my command :S.

Very frustrating.

Answer (score 4):

Taking onboard Teneff's answer I realised that the timeout happens, because I mocked `shell.exec` successfully however I have used it's async version `exec(command [, options] [, callback])` so I tried first logging out the arguments and it worked.

All was left to do to call the callback and voila, my test works.

```
jest.mock('shelljs', () => {
  return {
    exec: jest.fn((_, __, callback) => callback())
  };
});
```

Answer (score 2):

[Teneff answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61075857/3956205) worked for me.
But as I wanted to mock different shell responses I improved it like that :

```js
const shelljs = require('shelljs');

jest.mock('shelljs');

describe('Run the test suite', () => {
  test('it should ...', async () => {
    shelljs.exec = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({ code: 0 }));
    ...
    expect(...);
  });
  test('it should ...', async () => {
    shelljs.exec = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({ code: 1 }));
    ...
    expect(...);
  });
});
```